# Chromedriver remote version:87 Disable save pass bubble

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am looking how to disable the "save password" bubble on Selenium webdriver.
I am using chrome version 87 in the remote client of the webdriver: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/remote_webdriver/remote_webdriver_client/

[image: selenium]

In prior versions the way to disable it was something like:

```
prefs = {
        "credentials_enable_service": False,
        "profile.password_manager_enabled": False
    }
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
```

But this is not working for me and I'm still getting the password bubble.

This switch and how to use it does not appear in the sources I have been looking for: https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/